# IE Array.sort not sorting with compare function

Tags: javascript, sorting, internet-explorer-11

Here is the code example which is not working properly in IE 11.

Element with id = END3 should be the last one.

Just don't tell me that I need to write sorting manually. It is not a big deal to implement it, but really?!

```js
var list = [{
    id: "SP1"
  },
  {
    id: "SP4"
  },
  {
    id: "END3"
  },
  {
    id: "SP2"
  }
];

console.log(
  list.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.id === "END3") {
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sort comparison function is behaving inconsistently. The function is supposed to return **`< 0`, `0`, or `> 0`**, not just `1` or `0`. If it's not returning those values, you're giving `sort` the wrong information to work with, because you tell it any comparison in which `a` isn't the desired value is equal. It's not guaranteed that `END3` will be passed as `a` at any point, so all comparisons will be "equal", so it's undefined what the result will be really. It's also possible that the inconsistency between `SP1, END3` ("equal") and `END3, SP1` ("greater") will affect the assumptions of the sorting algorithm.

```js
var list = [{id: "SP1"}, {id: "SP4"}, {id: "END3"}, {id: "SP2"}];


console.log(list.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.id === 'END3') {
    return 1;
  } else if (b.id === 'END3') {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}));
```

Comment: from mdn: "compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined."

Comment: There are such arrays which will always return 1, or -1 or only 0. Like in case of number comparison and input array [2,2,2,2,2,2], each compare call will return 0.

Comment: Yeah, but your return is inconsistent if you pass `SP1, END3` (→ equal) or `END3, SP1` (→ larger). The correct answer should be "smaller" and "larger" respectively. How that will affect the sort algorithm depends on the implementation details of the algorithm.

Comment: I clarified that the  likely issue is that `END3` is never passed as the `a` parameter, making all values "equal".

Answer (score 1):

Return `-1` instead of `0` in the else block. When the compare method returns `0` it leaves `a` and `b` unchanged.

```js
var list = [{
    id: "SP1"
  },
  {
    id: "SP4"
  },
  {
    id: "END3"
  },
  {
    id: "SP2"
  }
];

console.log(
  list.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.id === "END3") {
      return 1;
    }

    return -1;
  })
);
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Anyway the behavior is differs, which one is the correct? IE or Chrome?

Comment: @QuestionAndAnswer, Different browser implement different engine, so neither is incorrect